# How to add new columns in to data base table with huge data existing in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

I have huge data in the table like number of TB data.While adding new column in to that table its taking lots of time.
Suppose released 2.0 we are adding new columns in to table if we to want upgrade data base to each customer to release 2.0. In that upgrade for each customer taking lot of time. As per our requirements each release we are adding new columns in to data base table. Each customer have TB of data.
I need to do some poc on that while upgrading data base it should not take much time.
Is there any solution for dynamically add columns with out taking much time.

Comment: There is really no avoiding the long update time for adding a new column.  Dropping all indices on the table _might_ make the statement happen faster, but then you would have to add them back on the other end.

Comment: An alternative way it is in temporary sharding the table. I.e. you rename the table, create new table which contains all fields added for 2.0 version release and is joined to the table of previous version 1:1 (FK to old table with unique constraint), and create a view which combines these tables into one. DBA must find a time interval of enough length for joining shards into one table and put it instead of a view - but now he is free enough to plan this process.

Comment: I guess you're aware of this, but if adding columns is a regular occurrence, just to note that this can be symptomatic of poor design

Comment: What MySQL version and storage engine are we talking about here? MySQL has added "instant add column" with MySQL 8.0 (and on the MariaDB side it exists since MariaDB 10.3)

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Use `pt-online-schema-change`

Plan B:  Add the new columns in a 'parallel' table that has the same `PRIMARY KEY` as the current table.

Plan C:  Upgrade to MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.3 so you can have `ALGORITHM=INSTANT`.

Plan D:  Make a one-time addition of a `JSON` column (via Plan A/B/C).  Thenceforth, you can add new "columns" to it.

"adding columns is a regular occurrence" - Poor design.  Show us the schema so we can discuss specific alternatives.

Comment: actually we are using some customers for mysql and some customer for mssql. Majority of the customers are using mssql. We need some generalized solution for both the databases.

Comment: @madhusudhan - Condolences.  The differences between different brands of RDBMS are frustratingly many.  And even within MySQL, there have been significant advances, such as for this Question.